# how to change each key of json object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add some text at the start of each json object key.

```
  Object.keys(json).forEach(key => {
    json = json.replace(key, `_${key}`);
  });
```

I'm trying this method but it changes some values instead of adding _ at the start of each key.

Comment: How does your JSON look like?

Comment: is `json` is a string or a `object`?

Comment: its a json formate, I've stringfy it

Comment: if its stringified, then you can't do `Object.keys(json)`

Comment: so none of your key already has a starts with `_` right?

Comment: yes., but if i have javascript object ?

Comment: show sample json. you only want to change first level keys? how about deep nested objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are going right. You have to iterate over `Object.keys` and inside each iteration assign a new key with same value and delete the previous key.

Here we are appending a `-` before each key.

```js
function modifyKeys(obj){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        obj[`_${key}`] = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
        if(typeof obj[`_${key}`] === "object"){
            modifyKeys(obj[`_${key}`]);
        }
    });
}

var jsonObj = {a:10, b:{c:{d:5,e:{f:2}}, g:{}},i:9};
modifyKeys(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: No, he does not :) He has JSON representation of object, not an object itself. Anyway, even if you provide an object, if it has nested objects their keys will not be processed and prefixed.

Comment: Cannot create property '_0' on string

Comment: @afaq, you need to convert your json to object by using `JSON.parse()`. I have edited my answer. Please check now

Comment: Yes now I did it,,

Comment: it change the uper level.. but do not dig into json. only top keys are changes

Comment: @afaq, I have added a recursive function to update keys at every level. Please check that.